# Existence for overdetermined system of PDEs

Tags: calculus, matrices, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am interested in the **existence** of a **vector valued** solution $y = y(x, t) \in\mathbb{R}^n$ to a system of $2n$ equations: there are **twice more equations than unknowns**. More precisely:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be **matrix valued** functions $A, B \in C^1([0, L]\times [0, T]; \mathbb{R}^{n \times n})$. **Does the system** 
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \partial_x y(x, t) = A(x, t) y(x, t) \\
> \partial_t y(x, t) = B(x, t) y(x, t) 
> \end{aligned}
> \qquad \text{in } [0, L]\times [0, T]
> \end{equation}
>   with initial and boundary conditions (with $g \in C^1([0, T]; \mathbb{R}^n)$ and $y_0 \in C^1([0, L]; \mathbb{R}^n)$)
>   \begin{equation}
> y(x, 0) = y_0(x) \quad \text{for }x \in [0, L]\\
> y(0, t ) = g(t) \quad \text{ for }t \in [0, T]
> \end{equation}
>   **have a solution $y \in C^1([0, L]\times [0, T]; \mathbb{R}^n)$?**

(Here, $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ denotes the square matrices of size $n \times n$ with real coefficients.)

Writing the equations in integral form, $y^1$ is solution to $\partial_x y^1 = A y^1$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
y^1(x,t) =& y^1(0, 0) + \int_0^t \partial_t y^1(0, s) ds \\
&+ \int_0^x \partial_x y^1(\xi, 0) d\xi + \int_0^x \int_0^t ((\partial_t A) y^1 + A \partial_t y^1) d\xi ds
\end{align*}
while $y^2$ is solution to $\partial_t y^2 = B y^2$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
y^2(x,t) =& y^2(0, 0) + \int_0^x \partial_x y^2(\xi, 0) d\xi \\
&+ \int_0^t \partial_t y^2(0, s) ds + \int_0^x \int_0^t ((\partial_x B) y^2 + B \partial_x y^2) d\xi ds.
\end{align*}

> Assume that the following **compatibility conditions** hold:
>   \begin{align*}
> \partial_t A + A B  = \partial_x B + B A,\qquad \text{in } [0, L]\times [0, T]
> \end{align*}
>   and $g(0) = y_0(0)$.

In this case, if $y$ is solution to both systems, then the expressions for $y^1$ and $y^2$ coincide and are equal to
\begin{align*}
y(x,t) =& f(0) + \int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}y_0(x) d\xi + \int_0^t  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}g(s) ds \\
&+ \int_0^x \int_0^t ((\partial_x B) y + B A y) d\xi ds
\end{align*}

> But how can we show that there **exists** $y$ solution to **both** $\partial_x y = A y$ **and** $\partial_t y = By$? Which method(s) would you suggest?
>   Do we need to add assumptions to obtain existence?

Also asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347247/uniqueness-but-no-existence